# What is a fast way to group values by index?

Tags: matlab

I have an array of indices, I, and values, X, and want to make a cell array C, so that C{i} = X(I==i). What is the fastest and best way to compute C?

The most straight forward way is to evaluate `C{i} = X(I==i)` for all unique i in I (approach 1):

```matlab
for i = unique(I)
    C{i} = X(I == i);
end
```

Another naïve approach would be to loop over all i in I and append the corresponding x to C (approach 2):

```matlab
C = cellfun(@(x)(zeros(1,0)),cell(1,max(indices)),'UniformOutput',false);
for j = 1:length(I)
    i = I(j);
    C{i} = cat(2,C{i},X(j));
end
```

Neither approach is very fast. To benchmark, let's generate some test data:

```matlab
I = floor(rand(1,N)*M)+1;
X = rand(1,N);
```

With `N = 1000000, M = 1000` the two approaches take:

- Approach 1: 4.79 seconds
- Approach 2: 11.1 seconds

Here, approach 1 is best (still very slow). Changing the parameters of the problem to `N = 1000000, M = 10000` changes things significantly:

- Approach 1: 48.5 seconds
- Approach 2: 10.3 seconds

Basically, both approaches are orders of magnitude too slow. What is the best way to evaluate C?

**Edit:** The correct answer is obviously Jonas' below. I am attaching benchmark results for reference. Compared to the above methods, the order of elements in C is different. Apart from that, the following gives identical output:

```matlab
C = accumarray(I',X,[],@(x){x'})';
```

- `N = 100000, M = 1000`: 0.0397 seconds
- `N = 100000, M = 10000`: 0.145 seconds

Comment: Note that for better speed comparisons, you should pre-assign `C` as `C = cell(max(indices),1);`

Comment: Yes, I actually did that, but left it out for clarity. It had no significant impact on the run times in these cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest way to write (and quite possibly the fastest to run) is `accumarray`

```
C = accumarray(I,X,[],@(x){x});
```

Comment: Thanks. accumarray seems very useful for a great number of applications. Typically for Matlab though: Instead of optimizing the language so that the idiomatic way is fast, they add special case functions. It would not be hard for Matlab to recognize the structure of the first approach above and evaluate it just like accumarray (the structure of which it in fact represents perfectly).

Comment: @digitalvision: the "idiomatic way" in Matlab doesn't involve a loop. Instead, it is either a matrix operation, or a specialized function. And yes, once you get the hang of it, `acumarray` is very useful.